# which version of apache to install on a windows 64 bit OS?

Tags: windows, apache

I got a new machine whose OS is windows XP professional x64 edition.  Which version of Apache should I install?  There doesn't seem to be a build for win 64, I can just see a build for win 32, will it work with win 64?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The win32 build will work with win64.

Follow the tutorial located [here](http://www.ricocheting.com/how-to-install-on-windows/apache) and you'll be up and running quickly.

Comment: I don't like xampp.  Let me install Apache and come back and mark this answer, once everything works fine.

Thank you.

Comment: Why on earth would he want xampp, if all he wants is Apache?